# Manhua story with a martial artist who is ranked as a God of War

Tags: story-identification

The story begins with a man who is a martial artist who is ranked as a God of War, and the enemy (Demon Lord or something I think) thinks that they killed him. After that the messenger of the enemy appears (wearing a robe with a hood to conceal his face and there was a lot enemies surrounding their leader [again the Demon Lord, I think]). He then reveals his identity by removing his robe, and surprisingly he is the God of War. All of the enemy leader’s subordinates attack him, but he defeats them with ease. Then they chatted a bit and then clashed with their full strength. They kind of created a big force.

In a different scene a scientist called their president (whose name is Silvi, I think). There was this portal that they are working on, and then they were testing it, and the God of War appears, and another one appears (a girl with a robe with a staff). Then the president watches (she was in a robot by the way), the man (GoW) quarrelling with the girl; meanwhile the president doesn’t know what they're saying and asked the scientist to translate it but couldn't. Then the president captures the GoW; then he shocks the people by crushing the robot’s arm (the president was inside), then the GoW and the girl fought, creating a time vortex like the one when GoW fought the barbarians' lord or the Demon Lord.

These are chapters 1-3.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Trinity Wonder](http://webtoon.daum.net/webtoon/view/TrinityWonder) by the authors of *The Breaker*. From [the wikia](http://trinity-wonder.wikia.com/wiki/Trinity_Wonder_Wikia):

> Trinity Wonder centers around three individuals from different parallel worlds: martial artist Gang Wu-Jin (Murim), mage Emily (Fantasy), and tech entrepreneur Sylvia Walden (futuristic Asadal).
>
> Each of them have lived their lives without knowledge of the bigger universe until that (un)fateful moment when a wormhole brought Wujin and Emily into the modern present through Sylvia's experimental teleportation gate.
>
> Chaos then ensues as the trio work together to uncover how to go back their respective worlds.

[Gang Wu-Jin](http://trinity-wonder.wikia.com/wiki/Gang_Wu-Jin):

> Gang Wu-Jin (simply referred to as Wujin) is a renowned martial artist from the Murim world who was known there as the greatest "God Dragon". He was an influential leader and warrior of the Murim Alliance that spearheaded the war against the Demon Sect until his disappearance.

....

> The Murim world is in a state of war between the Alliance and the Demon Sect. Wujin rose to become the Alliance's undisputed champion - the one who can evenly fight against the Demon King Lim Hoh-Tan. In one of the battles, Wujin and Hotan fought one-on-one against each other. During this battle, Hotan won by pushing Wujin over the Murim cliffs, the supposed edge of the Murim world. Wujin was then assumed to have died and the Alliance retreated in the face of being decisively routed. The Demon Sect then withdrew, satisfied by their victory, to consolidate their gains.

Comment: Can you possibly [edit] in any more details/plot points which suggest similarity to the described post?